# C# object as JavaScript function param

Tags: c#, javascript, web

I have next C# code:

```
public class Login
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

    public Login(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        this.UserName = UserName;
        this.Password = Password;
    }
}

protected const string JsonFunctionFormat = "function {0}(){{ {1}; }}";
        protected const string JsonReturnFunctionFormat = "function {0}(){{return {1};}}";

public static void Fill(HtmlDocument Document, string FillerFunctionCode, Login LoginData)
    {
        if (Document != null)
        {
            HtmlElement dataElement = Document.CreateElement(OrganizationCardFiller.ScriptHtmlElementName);
            IHTMLScriptElement domDataElement = (IHTMLScriptElement)dataElement.DomElement;

            domDataElement.text = string.Format(LoginFiller.JsonReturnFunctionFormat, LoginFiller.GetLoginInfoFunctionName, LoginFiller.ConvertToJSon(LoginData));
            //domDataElement.text += string.Format(LoginFiller.JsonFunctionFormat, LoginFiller.FillerFunctionName, FillerFunctionCode);
            domDataElement.text += FillerFunctionCode;

            HtmlElement headElement = Document.GetElementsByTagName(LoginFiller.BodyHtmlElementName)[0];

            headElement.AppendChild(dataElement);
            //Document.InvokeScript(LoginFiller.FillerFunctionName);
            //Document.InvokeScript("FillLoginForm", new object[]{LoginFiller.ConvertToJSon(LoginData)});
            //object[] args = { LoginFiller.ConvertToJSon(LoginData) };
            //Document.InvokeScript("FillLoginForm", args);
            Document.InvokeScript("FillLoginForm", new object[] { "{UserName:'user',Password:'pass'}" });
        }
    }

    private static string ConvertToJSon(object ConvertingObject)
            {
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                return serializer.Serialize(ConvertingObject);
            }
```

And next JavaScript function:

```
function objToString (obj) {
    var str = '';
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            str += p + '::' + obj[p] + '\n';
        }
    }
    return str;
}

            function FillLoginForm(login)
            {
                var userName = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctplhMain_Login1_UserName');
                var password = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctplhMain_Login1_Password');
alert(objToString({test: 123, test2: '12345'}));
alert(objToString({""UserName"":""username"",""Password"":""veryHardPassword""}));
                alert(typeof(login));
alert(login);
alert(objToString(login));
                if(userName!=null)
                {
                    userName.value = login.UserName;
                }
                if(password!=null)
                {
                    password.value=login.Password;
                }
            }
```

Alerts with `"{test: 123, test2: '12345'}"` and `"{""UserName"":""username"",""Password"":""veryHardPassword""}"` works great, but  `typeof(login)` return "unknown" and *"login"* with *"objToString(login)"* return Empty. As you can see, I tryed different variant, but all of them returns Empty. What's I make wrong, why login param don't pass to JavaScript function by correct format?

Comment: are you sure that `Fill` is executed?

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure

Comment: can you provide a bit more information about your code? what kind of project you use?